# How to trigger code if Enter key is pressed in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move to first cell of next row of column "A" in excel whenever enter key is pressed in Column "H". My code so far is below;

```
Private Sub move_to_next_row(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)  
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (also gets triggered by the down arrow)

```
Option Explicit

Private col As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 8 And col = 8 Then
            Cells(.Row, 1).Select
            col = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
        col = .Column
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no KeyDown event or something similar for worksheets. You can only check if a cell in column H was changed and then move to the first column in the next row.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("H")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Cells(Target.Row + 1, "A").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What if column H contains formula?

Comment: @LEO The `Worksheet_Change` only triggers if a constant value in the column H is changed. It does not trigger if the result of a formula changes.

Comment: There are lot of things that can go wrong but then it is beyond the scope of the question. You can only show the way but to an extent and you have done your part :) BTW  [Interesting Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Answer (score 1):

**Not For Points**

Another way in case you want to trap the "Enter" key in Col H (*irrespective of whether user made a change or not in column H*)

**Credits**:

1. @Tom for `Application.OnKey`
2. @AsUsual for `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

Place this in the worksheet code area

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsName As String

    wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
    If ActiveCell.Column = 8 Then Application.OnKey "{Enter}", _
                                  "'MoveCursor" & Chr(34) & wsName & Chr(34) & "'"
End Sub
```

Place this in the module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveCursor(wsN As String)
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then GoTo CleanExit
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> wsN Then GoTo CleanExit

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select

CleanExit:
    '<~~ Reset the key to avoid undesirable sideeffects!
    Application.OnKey "{Enter}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, but I think it still has a glitch when using multiple workbooks. Haven't tested it but I think if you are in column H of that workbook and change to another workbook it will still use the `OnKey` so you would have to add a `Workbook_Deactivate` to deactivate the enter there too I think? Same for other worksheets in the same workbook (if it should only affect one worksheet)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Good Point. Try it now

Comment: Nice, looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ThisWorkbook` Object place the following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "move_to_next_row"
End Sub
```

And then run using <kbd>F5</kbd>

Then in a normal module place

```
Sub move_to_next_row()
    Dim SelectRng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveCell.Column = 8 Then
        Set SelectRng = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7)
    Else
        If Application.MoveAfterReturn Then
            Select Case Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
                Case xlToLeft
                    Set SelectRng = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
                Case xlToRight
                    Set SelectRng = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
                Case xlUp
                    Set SelectRng = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
                Case xlDown
                    Set SelectRng = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SelectRng Is Nothing Then
        SelectRng.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you press the enter key `move_to_next_row` will be called. If the `ActiveCell` is in column `H` it will move the `ActiveCell` to Column `A`

Comment: This will kill the normal behavior of the Enter key (in any other place than column H)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Whilst not a great way to achieve it the Enter key seems to still work fine in my test - Have tested in column H and other columns

Comment: Strange, because in my test after `Application.OnKey "~", "move_to_next_row"` Enter doesn't switch to the next cell anymore in my sheet (only column H jumps as expected). If I then run `Application.OnKey "~"` it works again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ah I see what you mean - have handled it in my update. I thought you meant it wasn't calculating

Comment: @SiddharthRout You can use `Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "move_to_next_row"` to trap that one

Comment: @SiddharthRout yup agreed - was just intending to demonstrate another way of achieving it as Excel doesn't have a proper way of implementing this.